# Law of sines - Two calculators two different answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am solving a triangle using the law of sines:

a = 75 b = 100 c = ?

Angle A = 30° Angle B = ? Angle C = ?

I did

sinB / 100 = sin30 / 75

SinB = (100sin(30°))/75

SinB = .6667

Sin^-1 (.6667) = Angle B = 41.8°

However in the online calculator I used it [Picture of the online calculators work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Umy.png) is saying that using those same numbers Angle B is = to 71.2°

Comment: Is your calculator set to radians accidentally? - The answer is definitely 41.81 degrees - what online calculator did you use?

Comment: http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/triangle-law-of-cosines.php and I plugged in the side a, side b, and Angle A

Comment: Aren't you using the law of *sine* though? That calculator is only for cosine... also I can't find the option for two sides and an angle.

Comment: Ah I found the right calculator and got 71.2 degrees as well. But 41.81 is correct.  I would just avoid using the online calculator altogether, it isn't necessary.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help I just wanted to make sure I did indeed get the correct answer

Comment: @Inazuma If you post instead of comment on this thread I can mark your answer as solving the question

Comment: Sure looks like a coding problem on that site.  This SSA triangle problem has two solutions and the site gets the _second_ solution angle correct, which is the obtuse angle with sine of $ \ \frac{2}{3} \ $ .  That is $ \ 180º \ - \ 41.81º \ = \ 138.19º \ $ .  So for some reason, the code is messing up the acute angle solution but doing the obtuse angle solution properly.  Ohhhkay...  (I used this page:  http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/triangle-law-of-sines.php  with the pull-down menu set to calculate 'angle B from b, A, a' . )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The online calculator is incorrect - be wary of many online sites, they may be using a formula of some other kind.

Your working is correct and the answer was confirmed to be 41.81 degrees using the law of sines.